# line break with align (and left brace)

Tags: line-breaking, align, page-breaking, braces

I want to write a big system of equation (about 50 lines) and I found I can use the environment align with the option (? is it an option ?) allowdisplaybreaks[1].
But some of my equations are large... I found some solutions but not with align and I don't know how to combine them.

And if I can add a left brace to this system, my day will be made. (it's optional, but if I can have the three : page breaking, line breaking and left brace...)

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
\begin{document}


\begin{align}
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
 A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really think that a biggggg left brace would help readers?

Comment: I don't know... I can't imagine if I don't see it. But if it's not a left brace, maybe there is other solution to separate two big equations system.

Comment: i don't know of any decent way to allow page breaking and at the same time place a left brace around the whole thing.  some suitable explanatory prose preceding the system would be preferable, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities for splitting the large term, I use `aligned` here

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \begin{document}


    \begin{align}
         A_1&\!\begin{aligned}[t]=N_0(&\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')N_0(\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),
\end{aligned}\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
    A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
     A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).\\
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: And is there an automatic way ?

Comment: Mostly tex encourages manual linebreaking of of equations, just as with your outer align, you need to add `\\ ` at semantically meaningful places. It is possible in simple cases to make some kind of automatic line wrapping but it is unlikely to make as good results, and is not provided by `amsmath`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation.
Any idea for the left brace or something equivalent to separate two big equation systems ?

Comment: @Ccile I wouldn't use a brace especially not in a system that may break over a page, you can use `\\[10pt]` to introduce a visual break if you have two systems in the same alignment (or of course you can use two alignments) Do you really need to number every line?, it makes the output look very cluttered.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
I think it's better to numerate each equation to avoid to forget one equation, especially with nearly 50.
If I want to remove the number, I just have to use align*, right ? (is don't I correct ?)

Comment: @Ccile -- `align*` removes *all* numbers.  if you want to remove the number on just selected lines, use `\notag` or `\nonumber` just before the appropriate `\\ `.

Comment: @Ccile unless you refer to a particular line from elsewhere in the document the numbers don't serve any useful purpose really.

Comment: barbarabeeton Ok, thanks

David Carlisle I will use label and ref for some lines. Maybe I could add \nonumber to every line except those I will labeled and the last one ?

Comment: @Ccile  yes, it's a personal style choice not really a rule but I think just numbering the lines that you want to call out later helps to highlight them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried but something annoys me : the numerotation starts with the first equation I numbered... (Am I clear ?)
I want to "hide" the number. If the first equation has \notag, the first number should be 2 not 1...

Comment: @Ccile That would be so confusing for your readers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different take on using an `aligned` environment inside an `align` environment. It differs from David's solution purely in the way the line breaks are chosen.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')
\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')\\
&-\phi(\lambda;\Omega')\cdot N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),
\end{aligned}\\
A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).
\end{align}
\end{document}
```